# Is there a clean way to migrate an on-prem Dev Ops Server to HTTPS

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, devops, visual-studio-2022

I have an on-prem DevOps server and I use Visual Studio 2022 for development.  I have some local Nuget packages stored in the Artifacts of the DevOps Server.  Since the last Visual Studio update, I have been getting the error:

```
NU1803: You are running the 'restore' operation with an 'HTTP' source,
'http://mydevops:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/PROJ/_packaging/PROJ/nuget/v3/index.json'.
Non-HTTPS access will be removed in a future version. Consider
migrating to an 'HTTPS' source.
```

I am able to switch the DevOps Server to use HTTPS, but then Visual Studio can't find the Source Code Control.  I opened the .sln file and changed the source to use HTTPS on the SCC URL, but Visual Studio then just locks up when I open the project.  I use TFS SCC and Git SCC on different projects.  Is there a clean way to migrate the links for SCC to the HTTPS URL?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to do was open Team Explorer and click the plug icon at the top.  It fought me but I had to delete the existing reference to my DevOps server and put in the link to the HTTPS URL.  Then I had to manually edit each .sln file and everywhere it referenced the HTTP tfs, I changed it to reference the HTTPS tfs. For the Nuget Source, it was pretty straight forward to change the link in Settings/Nuget Package Manager/Package Sources.